# Modal parser using yacc

Tags: parsing, go, yacc

I am writing my first parser in yacc. I would like to parse a file that has 3 "modes":

- Statement mode
- Table heading mode
- Table row mode

I would like my parser to start out in statement mode, then when it sees a line consisting of minus signs, switch to table heading mode. When it sees another line of minus signs, switch to table row mode, and finally when it sees a third set of minus signs switch to statement mode:

```
statement...
statement...
statement...
----
table heading
----
table row
table row
table row
----
statement
statement
statement
```

One thing that occures to me, is that I could have 3 separate grammars which I would switch between in my [line feed loop](https://github.com/golang-samples/yacc/blob/master/simple/calc.y#L134). However, I don't know how to create multiple grammars in one `.y` file.

The other thing that seems like a possibility is using ["Lexical Tie-ins"](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/) (unfortunately, you'll have to search for that string in the document). However, the author of the yacc tutorial doesn't really tell me anything about these "lexical tie-ins" other than that "This kind of ``backdoor'' approach can be elaborated to a noxious degree. Nevertheless, it represents a way of doing some things that are difficult, if not impossible, to do otherwise." Which is hardly encouraging.

Comment: This doesn't look like a language for which bison isthe answer but you haven't described the structure of the "modes" so I could be wrong. It is easy enough to switch lexical mode in (f)lex; just search for start condition in the flex manual. That's probably all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating pseudo-symbols which I insert using the lexer:

```
line
    : TABLE_HEADING sentences ',' table_heading_columns ',' sentences
    {
      fmt.Println("TABLE_HEADING")
    }
    | TABLE_BODY table_body_columns
    {
      fmt.Println("TABLE_BODY")
    }
    | STATEMENT sentences
    {
      fmt.Println("STATEMENT")
    }
    ;
```